# JMeter incorrectly interprets the slashes in windows file path

Tags: java, windows, selenium-webdriver, path, jmeter

I need to provide a file path to selenium in JMeter to upload file on page

However if I write this:

```
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@id='versionFile']")).sendKeys('C:\\Users\\dsuhoparov\\test.docx');`
```

selenium throws error:

```
Response code:500 Response message:invalid argument: File not found : C:Usersdsuhoparov est.docx"
```

So it seems java/JMeter has problems with slashes, could someone help?

Comment: Did you mean "/input[@id=....."? Notice just one '/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use single forward slash i.e. `/`:

```
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@id='versionFile']")).sendKeys("C:/Users/dsuhoparov/test.docx");
```

or the escaped backward slash i.e. `\\`:

```
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@id='versionFile']")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\dsuhoparov\\test.docx");
```

Comment: Second solution is exactly the same as I did in my question, and the first doesn't work. Selenium can see path clearly, but seems it doesn't understand that it is a path, but not just a string
'Response code:500
Response message:invalid argument: File not found : C:/Users/dsuhoparov/test.docx'